# svn-bench and fsfs-stats binary usage

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn, benchmarking, fsfs

I looked upon the svn-bench and fsfs-stats binary tools in SVN 1.8 as mentioned in http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.8.html#new-tools

But I'm unable to use it through command line client. I'm currently using SVN 1.8.9. Is there any other place where i need to download these clients and install it? Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that you won't find these `fsfs-stats` and `svn-bench` tools in binary packages now. You have to build them yourself. Why do you need these tools anyway? Note that these are *not client-side tools*.

These tools [are pretty useless according to Mark Phippard](https://subversion.open.collab.net/ds/viewMessage.do?dsForumId=3&dsMessageId=501887), unless you are Subversion developer:

> I do not believe either of these tools have value to anyone other than
>   Stefan. He mostly created these tools to analyze various cache and
>   storage optimizations he has worked on.

As of `fsfs-stats`: [the tool becomes a subcommand of new `svnfsfs` tool](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc?view=revision&revision=r1594860) and the functionality *may* be moved to `svnadmin` in future releases.

P.S.: I've looked into this and command-line client binary packages by VisualSVN, SlikSVN, Algazam, CollabNet do not include these tools now. I assume they don't include `fsfs-stats` and `fsfs-bench` cause these tools are for Subversion experts only and are not intended to be used by majority of regular users.